# tcl checking fails

Tags: https, configure, tcl

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and after adding some files for the integration of evalvid 2.7 and ns-2.35, i enter `./configure` again from this directory:

> /home/user_name/Documents/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35

I got this error:

> checking Tcl http.tcl library... configure: error: Couldn't find http.tcl in       /http  /http2.5    /http2.4    /http2.3    /http2.1    /http2.0    /http1.0

Can someone help me fix this, thanks.

Comment: Try `locate http.tcl`. Does your configure script have a `--with-tcl` option?

Comment: yes it has but still doesn't work

Comment: I found the answer. Here it is: `./configure --with-tcl-ver=8.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: `./configure --with-tcl-ver=8.5`

see [the post of @gbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277446/ns2-installation-error-on-ubuntu-12-10)